# In which design layer i can put jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm new in Python/GAE and jinja2, and I want to present a schema of this architecture with displaying that in Layered, like this:

- Presentation Layer: HTML+CSS+JQUERY
- Business Layer: webapp2
- DAO Layer: (I don't know what I put here  when it's Python, I find some exemples for java thay put here  "JDO orJDO or low level API")
- Data Layer: appengine DataStore

**My questions:**

1. Regarding jinja2, where can I put it?
2. What can I put in DAO layer for Python/GAE

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are very artificial distinctions, and it's a mistake to assume that all apps have each of these layers, or that any particular function will fit only into one of them.

Jinja2 is a template language. It's firmly in the presentation layer.

There isn't really any such thing as the data access layer. If you really need to put something here, one possibility would be whichever library you are using to access the data: `ndb` or the older `db`.

Comment: thanks @Daniel for your answer , just for jinja2 ,if it s firmly in the presentation layer , why we use it in the business layer, i mean where i import it , rending template...

Comment: I don't understand that question at all.

Comment: Sorry if I had not understood this architecture ,  i mean if  jinja2  is Firmly in presentation only,  or I can represent it also  in business layer , because I see that I import this template in business with webapp2 and other library , and the treatment of variables passed to the template  is in the presentation layer  ,

Comment: You're making arbitrary distinctions here. You import jinja2 in webapp, which you've put in the "business" layer. But it doesn't do any business logic, it only does presentation logic.